Update of MutableStateFlow List doesn't work in Kotlin
I have a shared viewModel in which I am trying to update a MutableStateFlow list. I get the new item to save, but after adding it to that particular list, I don't find it in the list...
addOrUpdateTempTransport is called from my view.
private val _tempTransportDetails = MutableStateFlow<List<TransportView>>(listOf())
val tempTransportDetails: StateFlow<List<TransportView>> = _tempTransportDetails

val allTransportDetails = combine(
    _transportDetails,
    _tempTransportDetails
) { savedTransports, tempTransports ->
    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "Saved Transports = $savedTransports")
    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "Temp Transports = $tempTransports")

    val combined = savedTransports + tempTransports
    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "Combined without filter: $combined")

    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "Combined Transports: $combined")
    combined
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), emptyList())

fun addOrUpdateTempTransport(transport: TransportView) {
    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "Temp Transport before update: ${_tempTransportDetails.value}")

    val updatedList = _tempTransportDetails.value.toMutableList().apply {
        val index = indexOfFirst { it.id == transport.id }
        if (index != -1) {
            this[index] = transport // Mettre à jour l'élément existant
        } else {
            add(transport) // Ajouter un nouveau transport
        }
    }
    _tempTransportDetails.value = updatedList
    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "After update: ${_tempTransportDetails.value}")
}

Here the logs to help you to understand my non mother language :)
Thank you all.
Logs
EDIT
I tried with a new list, same result
fun addOrUpdateTempTransport(transport: TransportView) {
    // Créer une nouvelle liste distincte à partir des éléments de _tempTransportDetails
    val updatedList = mutableListOf<TransportView>().apply {
        // Parcourir chaque élément de _tempTransportDetails et l'ajouter à la nouvelle liste
        _tempTransportDetails.value.forEach { item ->
            add(item)
        }
        // Ajouter le nouvel objet transport
        add(transport)
    }

    // Mettre à jour _tempTransportDetails avec cette nouvelle liste
    _tempTransportDetails.value = updatedList

    // Log pour déboguer
    Log.d("StayDetailsViewModel", "Updated tempTransportDetails with new list: ${_tempTransportDetails.value}")
}


Perhaps_tempTransportDetails.value and _tempTransportDetails.value.toMutableList() are the same object. Try ensuring that you are creating a new list object, rather than possibly reusing the existing one.

I tested with a brand new list but same result

addOrUpdateTempTransport still looks strange. From what I gather you just want to add transport. Why don't you just use _tempTransportDetails.update { it + transport } then?

I tested by trying to inject a new line directly so that Compose detects and reloads. I read that an add or update is not detected by Compose

I cannot reproduce the issue, it seems to work fine as it is. Can you please verify this example you posted actually produces the erroneous behavior? Create a new project and just use the code you posted here to test if the problem can still be reproduced.

Thanks tyg, I created a simple project and tested it, it works... I really don't know what could crash the process on my main project... I will continue to investigate.
